# SMS messaging not available on iPad - how to enable?

Tags: ipad, messages, sms

I am unable to text to anyone other then other iOS users...  I want to enable "allow SMS messaging when iMessage is unavailable" but it is not an option - how do I set this up?

Comment: Please don't use an ALL-CAPS title.

Answer (score 1):

You need an SMS-capable device, like an iPhone or iPad with a SIM & text messaging plan.

See [Use Messages with your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201287)

If you have a capable device & service plan, make sure SMS is switched on in Settings > Messages

[image]